# Converting from sub_match<const char *>' to 'const char *const &'

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying to map std::match_results data to my std::multimap variable. Here's the code:

```
#include "Precompiled.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tdd;

auto main() -> int
{
    auto filename = LR"(E:\stats.stats)";

    auto file = invalid_handle
    {
        CreateFile(
            filename,
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            nullptr,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            nullptr
        )
    };

    if (!file)
    {
        TRACE(L"CreateFile failed %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    auto size = LARGE_INTEGER{};

    if (!GetFileSizeEx(file.get(), &size))
    {
        TRACE(L"GetFileSizeEx failed %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    if (size.QuadPart == 0)
    {
        TRACE(L"File is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }

    auto map = null_handle
    {
        CreateFileMapping(file.get(),
        nullptr,
        PAGE_READONLY,
        0, 0,
        nullptr)
    };

    if (!map)
    {
        TRACE(L"CreateFileMapping failed %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    auto view = unique_ptr<char, map_view_deleter>
    {
        static_cast<char *>(MapViewOfFile(map.get(),
        FILE_MAP_READ,
        0,0,
        0))
    };

    if (!view)
    {
        TRACE(L"MapViewOfFile failed %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    auto r = regex{ "type:([IPB])\\sdur:(\\d{1})\\scpbdur:(\\d{1})\\sq:(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\saq:(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\stex:(\\d+)\\smv:(\\d+)\\smisc:(\\d+)\\simb:(\\d+)\\spmb:(\\d+)\\ssmb:(\\d+)" };

    auto begin = view.get();
    auto end = begin + size.QuadPart;

    auto logValues = multimap<char, double>{};

    auto i = cregex_iterator{ begin, end, r };

    int d = 0;

    for (i; i != cregex_iterator{}; ++i, ++d)
    {
        logValues.emplace((*i)[1], (*i)[4]);
    }

    TRACE(L"%d\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::sub_match' to 'const char *const &'

I tried static_cast but it doesn't work. Do I need to write conversion operator to std::sub_match to convert first value to char or is there something I am missing?

Also, in my second for loop, I want to go through i which is std::cregex iterator, since it has been incremented while it was being filled up with data, how do I reset it to go through it again? or is that done automatically? I couldn't find answer to this in the documentation.

Comment: Where is the regex? And why not just use match_result with regex_search() ?

Comment: @sln I'm sorry I am gonna update my original post with whole code. I didn't use regex_search() because as I understand it only returns matched string the first time it finds, and I needed iterator to go through huge text and get multiple matched data.

Comment: I hate to tell ya, all iterator's use regex_search at the core. Typical iteration is `while( regex_search(start, end, ...) ) { something something;  start = _M[0].second;, etc ... }`

Comment: @sln Good to know, thanks. But that doesn't solve my problem though because my search works just fine as well, I get the desired results, I am just interested how to get data returned from regex_search into my std::multimap variable. Whether I use iterators or not, regex_search is used and it stores the result into _M which is of the type std::sub_match<const char *>, just like the result that my search gives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't completed dereferencing the matches.  `(*i)[1]` returns a `const sub_match<BidirectionalIterator> &` object (where the type of your begin/end iterators goes in place the `BidirectionalIterator`).  This sub_match object includes a pair of iterators referencing the first and one-past-the-last characters in your source string for that match.

To get the character at that value, you need to do something like `*(*i)[1].first`.

For what you're showing, you don't need that first loop to count the number of matches.  If your actual code is more complicated, and you do need to run the loops twice, make a copy of the iterator before running it thru the first loop.

Comment: First result (*i)[1] is character anyways returned by cregex_iterator search so I don't need to add .first. I tried anyways and got same error message. It is a bit more complicated, I didn't want to put whole source file in my original post because it would be too much. First loop is going through 5MB+ text file so there's a lot of iterations going on. I had a flow in my original source, I realized that I don't need second loop at all. So only first part of my question remains.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm stupid sometimes, you are absolutely correct!